# Host a custom API in Apigee - howto

Tags: api, apigee

I have created a custom API for an application i'm developing with my team. The API is in PHP,actually using the CakePHP framework.

Can i host and use resources of Apigee for my API? Or i can simply manage the API through API dashboard,which means i have to host in another server (ex Rackspace) my API?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot currently host your PHP API on Apigee.  You would need to deploy it elsewhere as you mentioned and then point your API proxy to the deployed API.  We do have the option of running a Node.js application on Apigee.  If there is any interest in doing that, it is described here: http://apigee.com/docs/gateway-services/content/developing-nodejs-applications-api-platform.